# OpenVPN Revoke a certificate without the CRT file with Easy RSA

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn, openssl, certificate-authority

I'm confused, I have an OpenVPN server on Debian. The previous system administrator who was in charge of this server deleted the user certificates (.crt file) with the command "rm -f example.crt". (This is a great idea..)

We are now stuck, because deleting the crt file does not block access, the certificates are still valid I see it in the index.txt file and I cannot revoke them with "sudo ./easyrsa revoke please_delete_me" because the crt file no longer exists.

I have this:

```
Cannot be revoked because no certificate was found. A certificate was expected
at: /home/admin/easy-rsa/pki/issued/please_delete_me.crt
```

Here is an example of the index.txt file

```
V XXXXXXXXXX AAAAAABBBBBBBBCCCCCCC unknown /CN=please_delete_me
V ZZZZZZZZZZZ DDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEFFFFFFF unknown /CN=another_example_1
```

Does anyone here know how to regenerate crt file or clean up unused certificates without the damn file.

Comment: Change the `V` in the first column of the row which you want to revoke to `R`, then add another date after the 1st (between XXXXXXXXXX and AAAAAABBBBBBBBBCCCCCCC) to signify the revocation date. Finally issue a new CRL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain why EasyRSA needs a certificate file: it needs a *certificate serial number* to identify which certificate to revoke. CN is not unique, but serial is.

If you see `index.txt` file, look into it: it's just a text file with easy to understand [structure](https://groups.google.com/g/mailing.openssl.users/c/gMRbePiuwV0/m/wTASgPhuPzkJ). It's a tab-separated table, one certificate per line.

```
V<tab>yymmddHHMMSSZ<tab><tab>serial<tab>DN
R<tab>yymmddHHMMSSZ<tab>yymmddHHMMSSZ<tab>serial<tab>DN
...
```

First field is *Validity*, either `V` for valid or `R` for revoked. Then two fields with timestamps: first is always filled, it's the moment of *expiration*, and second is empty for valid certificates, and only filled for revoked — it's the moment of revocation. (Notice there are two consecutive tabs for valid certs, the "field" is between them.) Year is two-digit (without the century), and the timestamps are in UTC (Z means Zulu). All the "revoke" action does is to change to "R" and add the revocation date, then it signs a new version of CRL.

So, you locate a line with your certificate in that file and do those changes manually. Then regenerate a CRL:

```
openssl ca -gencrl -out ca.crl -config openssl.cnf
```

You can also revert a certificate from being revoked back into valid state this way.

---

In addition to `<commonName>.crt` EasyRSA often stores also a set of files in the form `<serialNumber>.pem` (at least, so does EasyRSA v2). These are the same certificates. You can use these to revoke too — just copy a pem file into name.crt and revoke name. Refer to `index.txt` to relate CNs and serials. You can also view the decoded certificate by executing `openssl x509 -in <file> -noout -text`.

---

Notice that from security standpoint you need to **regenerate the CA** and **recreate all certificates**. This is because old admin had an access to the private key of your CA; this means, he might be still possess the CA and so able to issue valid certificates without even your knowledge. Your VPN is compromised until you do that!

Comment: Thank you for your reply !

If I understand correctly, to revoke access, I can therefore modify the index.txt file manually and do something like this:

Before :
`V 241119083022Z  ABC unknown /CN=USER`

After :
`R 241119083022Z 231010000000Z ABC unknown /CN=USER`


And run the command `./easyrsa gen-crl` which seems to execute the openssl command

Comment: Yes. Backup your CA before (just tar the directory) and try this. It should help.